# Changing the choices in Django Model according to a field value

Tags: python, django, django-models

If for example, I have a class Summary,

each Instance of the class Summary, can be one subject:

```
    subjects = (
        ('english', 'אנגלית'),
        ('bible', 'תנ"ך'),
        ('history', 'היסטוריה'),
        ('civics', 'אזרחות'),
        ('language', 'לשון'),
        ('literature', 'ספרות'),
    )


class Summary(models.Model):
...
subject = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=subjects)
...
```

Now I've decided I want to hardcode some topics for each subject, so if `Summary.subject = "literature"` I want to add a field

```
subtopic = models.CharField(choices=literature_subtopics)
```

and make the choices equal to:

```
literature_subtopics = (
    ('poems', 'שירה'),
    ('short_stories', 'סיפורים קצרים'),
    ('plays', 'מחזות'),
    ('novels', 'נובלות'),
)
```

If the subject was English then `english_subtopics` would be used for the choices field.

I want to hard-code all these divisions because they will not change more than once every few years if at all, storing them in a database makes zero sense.

I need to somehow set up all these divisions for each subject, and make Django set the choices field for the subtopic appropriately.

can I override the init method to accomplish this somehow? I heard that's a bad idea and can break things.

Comment: I think you need Javascript.

Comment: I really don't think I need JavaScript, I'm trying to define something at the model level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the data doesn't change often, it seems most natural to put data in the database and Python in Python files. Your proposed solution seems like you're fighting the way Django wants to do things.

What do think of a database solution?

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hebrew_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Summary(models.Model):
    ...
    subject = models.ForeignKey("Subject")
    ...

class SubjectForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.none())
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4880869/1477364
        sub = kwargs.pop('parent_subject')
        super(SubjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        parent_subject = Subject.objects.get(name=sub)
        sub_subjects = Subject.objects.filter(parent=parent_subject)
        self.fields['subject'].queryset = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=sub_subjects)
```

Note that the code implies there will always be a parent Subject passed to SubjectForm. (You'll need a "root" Subject.)

Comment: This is fine but I just feel that using databases isn't the right choice here, I want a more brittle structure. Guess I'll have to rethink it

Answer (score 4):

You could set the choices dynamically using a function.

```
# models.py

def get_choices():
    choices_tuple_list = []
    ... # your logic to define choices
    return choices_tuple_list

class Summary(models.Model):
    ... # Summary definition
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Summary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field_by_name('subject')[0]._choices = get_choices()
```

[See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/)

Comment: Ok that looks good, but the logic needs to be according to what has already been chosen in a previous field, how would I go about that?

Comment: You need this just to save it? or to show this in a form?. You can pass some parameter to `get_choices(condition=None)`