# Using a callable/dynamic for queryset in ModelChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that is used to make a formset, like so:

```
class PreferenceForm(forms.Form):
    preference = forms.ModelChoiceField(SchoolClass.objects.currently_enrolling())
```

The method currently_enrolling() queryset returns a queryset which ModelChoiceField takes its choices from:

```
class SchoolClassManager(models.Manager):
    def currently_enrolling(self):
        return self.filter(semester=Semester.current_enrolment()).order_by("subject__name", "name")
```

This works until the data this queryset returns (i.e. the classes that are currently enrolling) changes - the form does not show the new classes that are now enrolling. Restarting django fixes the problem, but this is not an optimal solution. I presume this means this code is run once on startup, and not subsequently. Is there a way to make this work for a changing queryset?

Edit:
This is the code for current_enrolment inside the Semester (model) class:

```
@classmethod
def current_enrolment(cls):
    semesters = cls.objects.filter(enrolments_open=True)
    if len(semesters) == 0:
        return cls.objects.latest('pk')  # no match, so we'll use the most recently created semester
    elif len(semesters) == 1:
        return semesters[0]
    else:
        return semesters[0]
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880842/how-to-dynamically-set-the-queryset-of-a-models-modelchoicefield-on-a-forms-form

Comment: Can you show the `currently_enrolling()` method?

Comment: @knbk - added it to the question

Comment: What about `Semester.current_enrollment()`?

Comment: It returns the semester object that has been flagged as enrolling. It's a classmethod. Why would that matter?

Comment: It matters whether that method executes one query at import time or returns a lazy queryset that is evaluated every time the model choice field is used. Judging from your problem it's the former, but I can't really propose a solution without knowing the code.

Comment: understood - added requested code.